# Efficient way to find common relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've recently started learning Cypher. I have a database containing four users and films. Users can have can have `[:WATCHED] / [:WATCHLISTED] / [:FAVORITED]` relationships with films.

I want to get the films which all four users have watched. Here's a working query I've written:

```
match (u1)-[:WATCHED]->(f)<-[:WATCHED]-(u2),
(u3)-[:WATCHED]->(f)<-[:WATCHED]-(u4)
return u1, u2, u3, u4, f
```

I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way to do this. Or any another way, which I can't of. I'm asking this out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to hardcode a `User` node count, this query efficiently gets the count using the DB's internal statistics:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WITH COUNT(u) AS userCount
MATCH (f:Film)
WHERE SIZE((f)<-[:WATCHED]-()) = userCount
RETURN f;
```

This query does not return the users that watched the film, since that is literally *all the users* in the DB, and with a sufficiently large number of them your query can run out of memory -- or it can take a very long time for a client (like the neo4j Browser) to receive and process the results. I think the main point of a query like this is to find the films, not the users. If you really want to get all the users, a separate query will do: `MATCH (u:Users) RETURN u`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for example :

```
MATCH (f:Film)
WHERE size((f)<-[:WATCHED]-()) = 4
RETURN f, [(f)<-[:WATCHED]-(u:User) | u] as watchers
```

Here I assume that there is only one relationship of type `WATCHED` between a user and a movie, even if the user has watched the movie many times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all`:

https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/

This checks if a predicate is true for all elements.